# Easy ScnSocial Auth + Standard ZFC User in the login screen

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I would like to know if its possible to implement an standard ZFCUser login + auth with ScnSocial auth in ZF2 and to even carry multiple signup procedures at the same time.

I mean: User first day signs-up and logins with ZFC User standard system. Second day, he opts to signup and link his account with his Google Account via ScnSocial auth. I have to have track of the possibility that this user is the same, and he has multiple login possibilities.

Any recommended documentation to read how can this be achieved if possible?

Comment: This works as the default behaviour once the email address the user uses matches the one in their google / facebook / etc auth. Just setup ZfcUser and ScnSocialAuth and test it.

Comment: I'm going to test it, so I just have to put the default ZFCuser login system + the scnsocialauth buttons and the whole system makes the matching